# partitioning hard drive for windows 7 + ubuntu dual boot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

Below is what my partitions looked like in my PC (with windows 10). I don't recollect creating these so i guess these were created by PC manufacturer. Recently booted from USB and deleted all these. Just wanted to format my drive and maybe have a dual boot between windows 7 and ubuntu. Just had a few quick questions.

1. What is the system partition? Is this normally created by PC manufactures?
2. What does extended partition mean?
3. HDDRecovery seems to be some sort of recovery partition (i.e. if you boot from it you can probably salvage your installation). Is this something that is created by PC manufactures? Or is it created when we install windows?
4. How do partitions map to drive letters in windows? I know that the c:\ drive is where windows is installed and in my windows 10 installation i saw just two drive letters. Which partition is designated as d:\ drive? Also, why no drive letters for each partition?
5. Now, since i've deleted all these, any suggestions on how i might partition my drive (to enable windows 7 + ubuntu dual boot)? I could just replicate what i had but i'm not sure what i will have in the System or HDDRecovery partitions.

[image]

Comment: Dog you have GPT partition scheme in UEFI firmware?

Comment: Sorry, don't get the question.